# OpenTK crashes with Mono

Tags: opengl, monogame, opentk, mono

I've implemented OpenTK as a secondary renderer which would let me support Mac/Linux only to realize that for some reason, even without any modifications (new MonoGame project), the application would make mono crash, but it runs perfectly fine on .NET.

I've been looking for some templates and demos to start with OpenTK for Mono/Mac/Linux but all I can find is Xamarin Studio guides for iOS and Android.

Comment: Do you have the crash error message or anything like that?  OpenTK should work fine with Monogame.  Are you using OpenTK 1.1?

Comment: @Jon No error message, Mono just stops responding, as mentioned above, even newly created MonoGame projects starts when I attempt to launch using Mono, I'm using OpenTK 1.1.

Comment: If there's no error message and mono just hangs then you've probably created an infinite loop somewhere in your code.

Comment: @Pharap There are no infinite loops, the code is very basic, just the render loop and some code that draws lines based on the cursor's movement, as I have mentioned above, the sample projects without any modifications also crash as soon as I attempt to run them with Mono.

Answer (score 1):

Although you haven't provided many specific details about the crash, **I would highly recommend using the Mono Migration Analyzer to find any problems.**

The Mono Migration Analyzer (MoMA) is a tool designed by the Mono team to test whether your program makes any unsafe calls in its source code, or calls any unimplemented functions. **The tool should list any problematic calls or lines of code which you could try replacing with a Mono-friendly equivalent.**

[You can download MoMA here.](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/tools/moma/) It's recently become unsupported, but works well for the recent releases of Mono.

Sorry I couldn't provide a concrete answer to your question, but this is impossible to do without more details about your setup. If using MoMA does not help you, the rest of the Game Development Community and I would be happy to help you if you provided more details.

Comment: There is no error or specific details about the crash, Mono.exe simply stops responding when I attempt to launch any application that utilizes MonoGame (even a newly created MonoGame sample project), I've attempted different versions and builds of Mono and MonoGame, but the result is still an error-less crash (no dumps or logs as far as I can tell), MonoDevelop crashes as well when attempting to debug. I've given up on Mono after being unable to resolve the issue, I'll try MoMA anyway and also try to see if Windows' event logger catches anything to provide more details about the crash.

Comment: @CoMaNdO It could be something hardware/firmware related. Does the crash occur before a window even appears, or does the window appear then close, or does it open and hang? Has the window title been changed before the crash? It's useful to determine where the crash happened in MonoGame's initialisation so you can pinpoint the problem. Windows' event logger might be useful, but if it's a conflict between Mono and MonoGame/the windowing library I doubt it will even throw an error...